# undestand the meaning vs understand by the meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

1.''What do you understand the meaning of better life?"

2"What do you understand by the meaning of 
      better life?"

I want to know whether  these two questions are different in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct and can be shorten to:

> What do you understand by 'better life'.

Another example:

> I understand by God's being eternal that he always has existed and always will exist.

Some words needs a preposition (by, to, of, from ...) to take an argument and if you omit that preposition the sentence become ungrammatical. Specially, if they take more than one argument:

You say:

> The Police requested a grant **from** the government.

You can't say:

> *The Police requested a grant the government.

**Understand** takes a direct object without any preposition like:

> I can understand **the lesson**.
>
> I understand that the God always has existed and always will exist.

In your sentence "**what**" plays this role and "What do you understand" is a complete sentence, but for its other argument it needs "by" preposition

> What do you understand by 'democracy'.
>
> I understand by 'democracy' that everyone has the right to to take part in the government of his country,
>
> I understand that everyone has the right to to take part in the government of his country.